# Accessing a Key in JSON Response

Tags: objective-c, json, ios5, asihttprequest

How in the following JSON response can I check if **uids** is nil ?

```
{
height = 480;
pid = "F@dd705e6b96a6e894556c0db84870501e_d97383cc80238c38b8907d99690fa1c9";
tags =     (
            {
        attributes =             {
            glasses =                 {
                confidence = 97;
                value = false;
            };
            smiling =                 {
                confidence = 97;
                value = false;
            };
        };
        center =             {
            x = "60.83";
            y = "75.21";
        };
        gid = "<null>";
        height = "49.58";
        label = "";
        manual = 0;
        nose =             {
            x = "76.21";
            y = "77.16";
        };
        pitch = "-5.55";
        recognizable = 0;
        roll = "-0.45";
        uids =             (          // <<<<<========== UIDs Key
        );
        width = "66.11";
        yaw = "-19.56";
    }
);
url = "http://face.com/images/ph/a6e529853432599dad6da996746cb070.jpg";
width = 360;
}
```

When I try :

```
if ([[[[photo objectForKey:@"tags"] objectAtIndex:0] valueForKey:@"uids"] count] == 0)
```

It keeps returning FALSE all the time.

I'm able to access a lot of these keys successfully. But it's just this one key that's giving me issues.

Like, to access the **url** key, I am using :

```
[photo objectForKey:@"url"];
```

And it's working absolutely fine.

What am I doing wrong with the **uids** key ?

Comment: Did you parse the string to get a dictionary?

Comment: Yes I did, and I'm able to access a lot of these keys successfully. But it's just this one key that's giving me issues.

Comment: Are you able to get pitch or roll?  And, do you know that [uids count] is sometimes not 0?